# Can AWS auto scaling run custom code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Can AWS autoscaling invoke custom code when scaling up or down instances? In other words, given the pre-existence of some arbitrary `launch_instance.sh` script that launches and configures one's instances, can that be integrated into the autoscaling workflow?

I believe the answer to this question is "no, you need to bake the things that `launch_instance.sh` does into an AMI and execute that when the instance launches", but I'd appreciate confirmation in case I missed some documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually set that up in userdata within the launch configuration. Some AMI's have cloudinit and will execute userdata automatically, but otherwise you can bake something into the AMI that will check the instance metadata for userdata.

More information about Cloudinit: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Comment: I see, although that sounds like in any case I've got to move stuff out of the external shell scrip in any case.